# How to get each value individually from a form using ajax and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, web

I'm trying to get each value individually so that then i could send it to my html file but i can't figure out how to get the values individually. Right now i only get the values by using an array but im not sure how to get all values individually.

HTML below

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="array.php">
  <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-3">
     <label for="date">My Birthday is</label>
     <input type="date"  name="Date" class="form-control" id="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YY">
</div>

     <div class="form-group col-md-3">
     <label for="name">My Name is</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="My Name">
                          </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
     <label for="favColor">My Favorite Color is</label>
     <select name="favColor" class="form-control" id="favColor">
       <option selected>Choose</option>
       <option value="Red">Red</option>
       <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
       <option value="Green">Green</option>
       <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
       <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
       <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
       <option value="Black">Black</option>
    </select>
   </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="sign">My Sign</label>
    <select name="sign" class="form-control" id="sign">
     <option selected>Choose</option>
     <option value="Aries">Aries</option>
     <option value="Taurus">Taurus</option>
     <option value="Gemini">Gemini</option>
     <option value="Cancer">Cancer</option>
     <option value="Virgo">Virgo</option>
     <option value="Libra">Libra</option>
     <option value="Scorpio">Scorpio</option>
     <option value="Sagittarius">Sagittarius</option>
     <option value="Capricorn">Capricorn</option>
     <option value="Aquarius">Aquarius</option>
     <option value="Pisces">Pisces</option>
    </select>
   </div>
```

Ajax code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#form').on('submit', function (e){
                  e.preventDefault();
                  var formData = $(this).serialize();

                  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'array.php',
                    data: {formData: formData},
                    success: function(data){
                      //what to do here
                      //alert("data saved: "+ data);
                      $('#test').append(data);
                    }
                  })

                });


              });
```

PHP Below

```
$data = ' ';

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
        echo $data .= " $key = $value ;";
    }
```

Comment: What is the end result you're looking for? To add more fields to the ajax data call or just end up individual php variables?

Comment: i just want to get each individual php variable because i then want to send each individual variable to the html file to display it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to do. But, if you want to access the form data without accessing directly the array, you could use the function `extract`.
Using your code as an example, you can access the indexes as variables.

```
<?php 
extract($_POST['formData']);

// both echos will show the same information
echo $_POST['formData']['date'];
echo $date;

// both echos will show the same information
echo $_POST['formData']['name'];
echo $name;

// both echos will show the same information
echo $_POST['formData']['favColor'];
echo $favColor;

//both echos will show the same information
echo $_POST['formData']['sign'];
echo $sign;
?>
```

In this example, both echos will show the same information as a result of `extract` function.

If you want more information about the `extract` function, please see [php's documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/function.extract.php).

Comment: okay thank you ill look at the php documentation. what i want to do is to have each variable alone so that i can then send that variable back to the html file to display the information

Comment: The function `extract` remove each index from an array and create variables using the index key as each name. So if you have an array with an index key 'name', after using the extract function, you will have a variable called $name. Let me know if you didn't understant.

Comment: so will this variable $name equal all variables or will i have to do something like $name[1] to get the favColor variable if that makes sense?

Comment: There will exists a var to each array index. Following your example, there will exists variables called $date, $name, $favColor and $sign. Got it?

Comment: okay yeah i get it, but now when i try to echo each variable using the code you showed me nothing gets echo out. I even tried echo $favColor and nothing got echoed out. any clue why?

Comment: I saw right now that part from your code: 
`data: {formData: formData}` 

So, you have to replace this part 
`extract($_POST);`

to that 
`extract($_POST['formData']);`

Comment: okay so when i try this it only echos out "D" for all the variables and i also tried it another way and it did the same. any clue why? sorry im very new to PHP so im trying to figure out getting values in forms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202835/discussion-between-rodrigo-alves-and-marcopolo).

Answer (score 0):

The form is posted to 'formData'.

```
$formData = $_POST['formData'];

$name = $formData['name'];
$favColor = $formData['favColor'];
```